# anyone knows the flex metadata mechanism

Tags: apache-flex, flexunit

When I use flexunit for tests, I confused about the metadata like [Test], [Test(async, ui)], anyone knows how does the metadata parsed by the flex? `how to define my own metadata`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Test(async)] when you're waiting for an asynchronous event in a test method.
Async tells the framework not to declare the method a success just yet, and that there is something else (an event) we need to account for to make that decision.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know how to define customer metadata?

Comment: You will find an example here :
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=showdetails&postId=11907